# How to determine Ubuntu startup level?

Tags: ubuntu, startup, init.d

We're planning to migrate from an older version of Ubuntu to (10.x) to the latest release of Amazon Linux. I'm trying to identify how to replicate the K and S scripts in the rc0.d, rc1.d etc directories.

My question is, how to determine which is the default level? There is no /etc/inittab, and the man page says it's been replaced by files in /etc/init. But they rcx.d directories contains references to specific apps within our system, while the /etc/init contains a bunch of ".conf" files. I'm thinking this somehow points to the rcx.d directories, perhaps via the rc.conf, rcS.conf or rc-sysinit.conf but can't lock down the actual startup level.

Also any general thoughts on migration from Ubuntu to Amazon Linux would be welcome.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is an OS question and not a programming question. You may be able to get help at another [se] site such as [ubuntu.se] or [su].

Answer (score 0):

Quoted from "Ask Ubuntu":
Ubuntu has replaced the traditional SysV init with Upstart. To somewhat stay compatible with SysV or runlevel based init, Upstart still supports the SysV traditions.

You can find (and change) the default runlevel in the /etc/init/rc-sysinit.conf file. The following command will do:

```
$ grep "env DEFAULT_RUNLEVEL" /etc/init/rc-sysinit.conf 
env DEFAULT_RUNLEVEL=2
As you can see the default runlevel is 2, you can also change it to your desired runlevel.
```